# Full Calendar Events not working

Tags: node.js, fullcalendar, electron

I have written fullcalendar code in one HTML file and want to use it in other HTML file in div tag, I did this by calling javascript function in which I set the innerHTML of div tag to object tag like:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object class="preventScroll" id="calObj" type="text/html" data="Calendar.html" height="100%" width="100%" align="left"></object>';
```

It is rendering the calendar in div with id "content" but the `dayclick` and `eventclick` are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you should try and add it as an dependent object rather than rendering it as html.

e.g:

document.getElementById("content").appendChild(calendarObject)

You loose the event binding because you are rendering an html and not "live" object